# Stop all further validation if multiple validation for first field fails

Tags: fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to write the rules for validating field for the validation.

At first i want to check if `Location Id` is `empty`, `null` or if that `exist` in the database, and then only processed further for other validation.

But, with the code i used, only check if `empty`, it does not stop if `Location Id` does not exist in the database.

**Register Model**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public long LocationId {get;set;}
    public long FirstName {get;set;}
    public long LastName {get;set;}

    //...other property to be added
}
```

JSON i am passing to API:

```
{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LocationId": "1234534",
}
```

The `location id` does not exist in the database: But i am getting the response as:

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "FieldName": "LastName",
            "Message": "'Last Name' must not be empty."
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "LocationId",
            "Message": "Invalid request."
        }
    ]
}
```

Validation rule i am using:

```
public class RegisterModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterModel>
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public RegisterModelValidator(DbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
        RuleFor(req => req.LocationId)
          .NotEmpty().WithMessage("param1 is missing.")
          .Must(IsValidRequest).WithMessage("Invalid request.");

        When(x => x.LocationId != null, () => {

            RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.LastName).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().NotEmpty();

        });

    }

    private bool IsValidRequest(string req)
    {
        var locationId = long.TryParse(req, out long result) ? result : 0;
        return _context.Locations.Any(x => x.LocationExtId == locationId);
    }

    private bool BeAValidDate(string value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        return DateTime.TryParse(value, out date);
    }
}
```

In my condition what i want is if the `location id` is missing or does not exist in the database, the validation should stop immediately, it should not check for the other field.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#setting-the-cascade-mode), its mentioned as

> Setting the cascade mode only applies to validators within the same RuleFor chain. Changing the cascade mode does not affect separate calls to RuleFor. If you want prevent one rule from running if a different rule fails, you should instead use `Dependent Rules` (below)

So can you try it like this using **Dependent Rules**

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull().NotEmpty()
          .DependentRules(d => d.RuleFor(req => req.LocationId)
          .NotEmpty().WithMessage("param1 is missing.")
          .Must(IsValidRequest).WithMessage("Invalid request."));
```

But i see if we use it like this, i think it should be repeated for multiple properties.

or a better option for you is using `PreValidate` since

> At first i want to check if Location Id is empty, null or if that exist in the database

[Prevalidate a property](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#using-prevalidate)

Comment: i have atleast 10 12 fields to validate! how can use on the `Dependent Rules`?

Comment: @aakash which is why i mentioned a better option called `prevalidation`

Comment: yeah `prevalidation` seems a good option, but i stuck some where when i tried to implement that!

Comment: @aakash stuck yet ?

Comment: I have three conditions to validate the `id` i.e. `NOT NULL`, `NOT EMPTY` and `ID exist in the database`. So, do i need to use three `if else` conditions to validate the `id` (in prevalidate)? and also as you see in the question about my error payload..i need to add the `fieldname` as well. but with the prevalidate i can get only the error message, but couldn't add the `fieldname` in the return responses.